# <head> tag is showing up as SyntaxError (1:1) Unknown word

Tags: angular, syntax, head

I started a new angular project using

`$ ng new my-angular-app --routing`

`$ npm init`

`$ npm install bootstrap` to get bootstrap downloaded

`$ git clone https://github.com/coreui/coreui-angular.git`to get coreui downloaded

and then I messed around with `app.component.html`, made a new empty component with the angular CLI, then renamed my component and needed to go back and change the component name in each file. I also added a `<head></head>` tag in `app.component.html` but later removed it. The next thing I know, I get this error.

```
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

  1 | <head>
    | ^
  2 |     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui/dist/css/coreui.min.css">
  3 |     test
```

How do I approach debugging this issue? This should be an innately recognized command in html, right? index.js doesn't have any html at all. No  tags, that's for sure.

Sorry, I'm not really sure what code to put in here because I don't see `<head></head>` anywhere and I am not sure where this error is coming from. `index.js` does not have anything to do with `<head></head>`.

Any explanation/feedback will be helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why did you add a `<head>` tag to an Angular component's template in the first place?

Comment: `<head>` tags should go in the index.html, not Angular components. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks! I was initially trying to add the coreui styles and I did not realize they needed to be in `index.html` at first. But after I removed the statement it seems to be stuck and still detects code that is not there :( Thanks for the help

Comment: You may need to clear your browser cache or restart your development server.

Comment: Thank you. That was the issue!!! It worked after I restarted everything!

Answer (score 0):

The closing head tag is missing.
the tag must be written as ,

Comment: Thanks, I should clarify in the question! I realized this but did not type it out!